# jquery multiple ajax request - causes problems with php objects

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, object

I am trying to process and update query for 1000 items at a time.
I tired settings cache to false, and even tried setTimeout to have a pause between requests.
Each request should take 5-6 seconds and then the process will never timeout, but after 4-5 requests it reaches server execution limit.

The problem is I need to use PHP objects in my update query.
every request seems to take longer so it seems the objects are looping in PHP

Is there anyway to stop this happening?

Here is the javascript code

```
function processIndex() {
    $.ajax({
        url: responder,
        dataType: "json",
        data: data,
        cache: false,
        async: false,
        error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown){
        //  alert('status:' + XMLHttpRequest.status + ', status text: ' + XMLHttpRequest.statusText + ' LIMIT ' + limitFrom + ', ' + limitTo);
            limitFrom = limitTo;
            limitTo  += 1000;
            processIndex('indexPrices');
        },
        success: function(data) {
                    limitFrom = limitTo;
                    limitTo  += 1000;
                    setTimeout(function() {
                        processIndex();
                    }, 1000);
                }
            });
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use 
http://www.protofunc.com/scripts/jquery/ajaxManager/

OR

https://gist.github.com/2470554

To queue up the ajax requests.

Another way of doing this is to send few records (say 50 records at a time) and loop through them in server side code.

You can combine these 2 solutions to get optimum result

Comment: Ok I will try looping through the data directly via PHP
Won't the request still timeout client side? for example it may then take upto 2 minutes for just 1 request.

Comment: holy cow! yoour one request takes 2 minutes... BTW Request time out can be managed in php code itself http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php.